# One elegant word for "body-part-specific" exercises?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

My context is that a gym provides several different physical exercises that work to strengthen different corresponding parts of the body; for example, the chest, back, arm(s), leg(s), etc.

I want to say that the gym provides exercises specific to different body parts, but I want to say this using an adjective in front of the word "exercises", e.g.,

> The gym provides ______ exercises.

and I don't want to use an expression with hyphenated words, such as "body-part-specific" exercises.

So is there any more elegant one word to say the gym provides "body-part-specific" exercises?

Comment: You might consider "targeted." This obviously doesn't explicitly state that the exercises are targeting different muscle groups, but, in the context of a gym, I think most readers would understand it to be implied.

Comment: Yeah, "targeted", or "focused".

Comment: You might compare/contrast "targeted" with "full-body" to say, for example "the gym offers *targeted* and *full-body* exercises." That should make the meaning clear.

Comment: The question seems well formed to me. And it has also has a specific answer. https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/drobson176.htm

Comment: Isn't that 'topical'?

Answer (score 1):

Preserving comments:

> You might consider "[targeted [exercises]](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22targeted+exercises%22)." This obviously doesn't explicitly state that the exercises are targeting different muscle groups, but, in the context of a gym, I think most readers would understand it to be implied. – MDHunter
>
> "targeted", or "focused". – Hot Licks
>
> You might compare/contrast "targeted" with "full-body" to say, for example "the gym offers targeted and full-body exercises." That should make the meaning clear. – Martin Burch